# React fetching data re-renders the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects with dates and ids in them, which I render from MongoDB. When rendered, the individual dates are selectable and I toggle a CSS-style to the selected item(s).
When I get the array of objects from the constant "allDates" at the top of the code, everything works as expected.
Inside the Element "Dates" I have my code to fetch the same data from MongoDB commented out. If I remove the comment and use it, the selection (toggling of styles) also works, but the DOM appears to be re-rendering on every click. How do I get rid of the re-rendering of all elements? Any help is much appreciated.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const allDates = [
  {date: "2021-01-21",id: "d1"},
  {date: "2021-02-21",id: "d2"},
  {date: "2021-03-21",id: "d3"},
  {date: "2021-04-21",id: "d4"},
  {date: "2021-05-21",id: "d5"},
  {date: "2021-06-21",id: "d6"},
  {date: "2021-07-21",id: "d7"},
  {date: "2021-08-21",id: "d8"},
  {date: "2021-09-21",id: "d9"},
];

const Test = () => {
  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);

  const selectionHandler = (itemIndex, id) => {
    if (selectedItems.includes(itemIndex)) {
      setSelectedItems((prevSelectedItems) =>
        prevSelectedItems.filter((item) => item !== itemIndex)
      );
    } else {
      setSelectedItems((prevSelectedItems) => [
        ...prevSelectedItems,
        itemIndex,
      ]);
    }
  };

  const Dates = () => {
    const actionDates = allDates;

    //const [actionDates, setActionDates] = useState([]);

    // useEffect(() => {
    //   const sendRequest = async () => {
    //     try {
    //       const dates = await fetch(
    //         `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/de/daten`
    //       );

    //       const responseData = await dates.json();

    //       if (!dates.ok) {
    //         throw new Error(responseData.message);
    //       }

    //       setActionDates(responseData);
    //     } catch (err) {
    //       throw new Error(err.message);
    //     }
    //   };
    //   sendRequest();
    // }, []);
    const action = actionDates.map((v, index) => {
      return (
        <div
          key={v.id}
          style={{
            borderBottom: selectedItems.includes(index) && "2px solid blue",
          }}
          onClick={() => selectionHandler(index, v.id)}
        >
          <p>
            <span className="fr_fontBold">{v.date} </span>
          </p>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return action;
  };

  return <Dates />;
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: using useState in a functional component or even setState in a class component, anytime you update your state the component will rerender itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

It is "rerendering" *all elements* because you are defining a new `Dates` React component inside the body of another component. Each time the outer `Test` component is rerendered (i.e. state and/or props update) it creates a new `Dates` component  and renders it. `Dates` isn't being rerendered, it's actually being unmounted/mounted as a new component each time.

## Solution

You would normally factor `Dates` into a standalone component but there are dependencies on the state and callbacks from the outer `Test` component scope. Based on usage my guess is that you accidentally merged the data fetching logic side-effect with the result rendering logic. These should be split out and the result should be returned from the `Test` component.

```
const Test = () => {
  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);

  const selectionHandler = (itemIndex, id) => {
    if (selectedItems.includes(itemIndex)) {
      setSelectedItems((prevSelectedItems) =>
        prevSelectedItems.filter((item) => item !== itemIndex)
      );
    } else {
      setSelectedItems((prevSelectedItems) => [
        ...prevSelectedItems,
        itemIndex,
      ]);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const sendRequest = async () => {
      try {
        const dates = await fetch(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/de/daten`
        );

        const responseData = await dates.json();

        if (!dates.ok) {
          throw new Error(responseData.message);
        }

        setActionDates(responseData);
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err.message);
      }
    };
    sendRequest();
  }, []);

  return actionDates.map((v, index) => {
    return (
      <div
        key={v.id}
        style={{
          borderBottom: selectedItems.includes(index) && "2px solid blue",
        }}
        onClick={() => selectionHandler(index, v.id)}
      >
        <p>
          <span className="fr_fontBold">{v.date} </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  });
};
```

#### Minor Optimization Suggestion

Use a Map or object to hold the selected id so you get constant-time (`O(1)`) lookups, as opposed to linear-time (`O(n)`). Just lookup in the `selectedIds` state for the current toggled selected value (`selectedItems[v.id]`). Converting `selectionHandler` to a curried handler also removes the anonymous callback handler.

```
const Test = () => {
  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState({});

  const selectionHandler = (id) => () => {
    setSelectedItems(ids => ({
      ...ids,
      [id]: !ids[id],
    }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const sendRequest = async () => {
      try {
        const dates = await fetch(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/de/daten`
        );

        const responseData = await dates.json();

        if (!dates.ok) {
          throw new Error(responseData.message);
        }

        setActionDates(responseData);
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err.message);
      }
    };
    sendRequest();
  }, []);

  return actionDates.map((v, index) => {
    return (
      <div
        key={v.id}
        style={{
          borderBottom: selectedItems[v.id] && "2px solid blue",
        }}
        onClick={selectionHandler(v.id)}
      >
        <p>
          <span className="fr_fontBold">{v.date} </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, also for the optimization suggestion, this solved my problem plus I understand why!